# When is the 4-hour downtime for free Heroku Postgres databases?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

The free tier for Heroku Postgres databases has "up to 4 hours of downtime per month". I think I might have run into that downtime while presenting an app,  and I'm trying to avoid problems like that in the future. Is there any way to find out when those 4 hours of downtime will occur? (Or, even better, could I schedule them during the middle of the night?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to find out when those 4 hours of downtime will occur? (Or, even better, could I schedule them during the middle of the night?)

[No](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-plans#hobby-tier):

> - Expected uptime of 99.5% each month.
> - Unannounced maintenance and database upgrades.